# Error in using getRichStringCellValue() of Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The following is my java code for reading a excel sheet content.

```
String urlcnt="";
for (Row row : sheet) {
 {
Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0);
urlcnt=firstCell.getRichStringCellValue();}
```

While compiling the above code am getting the following error.

```
ReadExcel.java:18: incompatible types
found   : org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString required: java.lang.String
                    urlcnt=firstCell.getRichStringCellValue();//This line is the cause for the error
```

Instead of storing the getRichStringCellValue() in a string, if I just print the value of the cell, it works fine. But I go ahead and store it in a string for further processing the problem occurs.

Kindly let me know what has to be done to proceeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `getRichStringCellValue()` returns a [HSSFRichTextString](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFRichTextString.html) or [XSSFRichTextString](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html) (depending on whether your cell is HSSFCell or XSSFCell) and you are assigning it to a `String`

Depending on your further processing -

Do you want to call `applyFont` or `clearFormatting` on the HSSFRichTextString ? 
then store it in a HSSFRichTextString/XSSFRichTextString.

If you actually want only the String text, use the [getString()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html#getString%28%29) method from the POI API

**UPDATE as per your comments**

Use it as

```
urlcnt=firstCell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
```

Comment: Can you be little more explanatory? how to store it in a HSSFRichTextString?

Comment: I want the String text alone. Further processing just includes comparing the string with the DB and adding it in the DB.

Comment: Thanks JoseK.. Now its perfect. Thanks again :)